# Component gradient calculation - OpenMDAO 1.7.x

Tags: openmdao

I'm using a "component" to "wrap" MDO Lab's Openaerostruct. When I declare

```
    self.deriv_options['type'] = 'fd'
```

In the component constructor, i dont have to declare the "linearize" method and it works fine. But I think that, by doing this, I'm not using the "entire" Openaerostruct capabilities, since this code already implemented "linearize methods" that should ( I guess) increase my code's performance.

So, I'm trying to set something like:

```
def linearize(self, params, unknowns, resids):
     self.OAS_prob.prob.calc_gradient(params,unknowns,mode='rev')
```

Also tried:

```
def linearize(self, params, unknowns, resids):
    self.OAS_prob.prob.calc_gradient(indep_list= ['alpha','taper'], unknown_list=['CL','CD'],mode='rev')
```

and:

```
def linearize(self, params, unknowns, resids):
    taper = params['taper']
    alpha =  params['alpha']
    CD= unknowns['CD']
    CL = unknowns['CL']
    self.OAS_prob.prob.calc_gradient(indep_list= [taper,alpha], unknown_list=[CD,CL],mode='rev')
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Can't determine size of unknowns ['CD', 'CL']
Can't determine size of unknowns [0.09583431121084045, 0.015186066036484149] ## for the last one
```

I have two questions:

1-Is there a way to use the "calc_gradient" in a component instead of a group, or am I trying something impossible?

2- If the first one is yes, shoud I expect some kind of performance improvement, since the Openaerostruct already has the "linearize" methods implemented?

Thanks in advance!!

Ps: what I'm trying to do is something similar to this simple example:

```
class Aero_Struct(Component):

    def __init__(self):
    super(Aero_Struct, self).__init__()

    self.add_param('taper', val=0.)
    self.add_param('alpha', val=0.)
    self.add_output('CD', val=0.)
    self.add_output('CL', val=0.)

    prob_dict = {'type' : 'aero',
                      'v':30.,
                      'optimize' : False}

    self.OAS_prob = OASProblem(prob_dict)

    surf_dict = {'num_y' : 7,
                     'num_x' : 2,
                     'wing_type' : 'rect',
                     'alpha': 2.,
                     'CD0' : 0.015,
                     'symmetry' : True,
                     'num_twist_cp' : 5,
                     'taper': 0.5,
                     'num_thickness_cp' : 2}
    self.OAS_prob.add_surface(surf_dict)

    self.deriv_options['type'] = 'fd'
    self.OAS_prob.setup()

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
       taper = params['taper']
       self.OAS_prob.prob['wing.taper'] = taper
       alpha =  params['alpha']
       self.OAS_prob.prob['alpha'] = alpha

       self.OAS_prob.run()
       unknowns['CD'] = self.OAS_prob.prob['wing_perf.CD']
       unknowns['CL'] = self.OAS_prob.prob['wing_perf.CL']
```

Comment: While this is technically a valid usage, I need to point out that you don't actually need to write a wrapper for OpenAeroStruct. Its already written in OpenMDAO and you could just instantiate the group and work with it directly. Then you will have access to the analytic derivatives and things should be more efficient

Comment: Yes, you are right...
When I started this project I thought this "wrapper" as a component would make the distributed architectures implementation easier... I was obviously wrong and now i have no time to "start over"...

Answer (score 1):

You are right that declaring your derivative type as "fd" will limit your performance and not take advantage of OAS's more efficient derivatives.

You are also on the right track that linearize is the function to define, and that you need to compute the derivatives on your OAS openmdao model, and return them. Here is what linearize looks like in a simple openmdao 1.7x model:

```
    def linearize(self, params, unknowns, resids):
    """ Jacobian for Sellar discipline 1."""
        J = {}

        J['y','x'] = 1.0
        return J
```

You need to pack the derivatives that are returned from the sub openmdao's calc_gradient into the J dictionary and return it. You may have to convert some of the param or unknown names if you used different ones in the OAS_prob than in the AeroStruct comp (for example, based on your code, it looks like taper is wing.taper in the OAS submodel.)

Altogether, it will probably look more like this.

```
def linearize(self, params, unknowns, resids):

    derivs = self.OAS_prob.prob.calc_gradient(indep_list= ['alpha', 'wing.taper'], unknown_list=['wing_perf.CL','wing_perf.CD'], mode='rev')

    J = {}
    J['CL', 'alpha'] = derivs['wing_perf.CL']['alpha']
    J['CL', 'taper'] = derivs['wing_perf.CL']['wing.taper']
    J['CD', 'alpha'] = derivs['wing_perf.CD']['alpha']
    J['CD', 'taper'] = derivs['wing_perf.CD']['wing.taper']

    return J
```

So mainly you forgot to unpack the derivatives from the calc_gradient call in the subproblem and return them to the outer openmdao.

Comment: Hey!  It worked using:

                J['CL', 'alpha'] = derivs[0][0] .......

for aero only problems my code is about 35% faster!!
In aerostruct problems, on the other hand, i'm loosing performance :(
This is happening due to the LN solver convergence:

     Solve in 'coupled': ScipyGMRES failed to converge after 1000 iterations
      [root.coupled] LN: GMRES   1000 | FAILED to converge after max iterations
........
Any ideias?
Thanks!